# List of possible exit codes from Roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've been seeing exit codes come out of roslaunch, example:

```
[process name] process has died [pid 1234, exit code -11].
```

I have seen mostly negative exit codes.  Are these signals/bash exit codes?  -11 appears to be a Seg Fault.  What's -6?

Is there a chart of the possible values it could send out and does it send out user exit codes as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11064/list-of-possible-exit-codes-from-roslaunch/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By convention, a negative exit code corresponds to the number of the signal that caused the process to die.  E.g., -11 is SIGSEGV, and -6 is SIGABRT.  For a list of signals, have a look at `/usr/include/bits/signum.h` (at least on my Ubuntu Lucid system, that's where they're defined).

Btw, this behavior and the meaning of the numbers isn't specific to roslaunch; roslaunch is just reporting back the exit code that the process gave when it died.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on 2016-05-13**:
I found the file with `find /usr -name signum.h` in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum.h`

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2019-10-30**:
You can also use `kill -l` to get a list of signals with their numbers.